# Setting a package install-path for composer

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

I've learned how to set a custom install-path for a composer package *on the project side*.

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "foobar": ["vendor/package"]
    }
}
```

However, I want to be able to set this dir name for this package *on the package side*, so in the `composer.json` file within my package repo. Placing the installer-path key there doesn't affect the installation dir and the package is installed in the default vendor/packagename dir.

How do you set the install path for a package within its own `composer.json`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the install directory for a package on the package, instead of on the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048491/how-to-set-the-install-directory-for-a-package-on-the-package-instead-of-on-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by adding `installer-name` to the `extra` key in the package's `composer.json` file.

```
"extra": {
   "installer-name": "foobar",
}
```