# How to set the install directory for a package on the package, instead of on the project?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I am working on creating a custom composer package. The composer package must install to a custom folder instead of vendors/ directory I want it to be installed in packages/. This is how my `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
"name": "demo/contentfeed",
"description": "This is yet another Lumen composer package wrapper",
"type": "lumen-plugin",
"version": "1.1.5",
"keywords": ["demo","lumen","drupal"],
"homepage": "https://github.com/gauravmehrasrijan/lumen-feeds",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "demo\\Contentfeed\\": "/src"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "installer-name": "packages",
    "installer-paths": {
        "packages": ["demo/contentfeed"]
    }
},
"license": "MIT",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Gaurav Mehra",
        "email": "gauravmehra1987@gmail.com"
    }
]
}
```

Before jumping here I also tried the solution posted in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679875/setting-a-package-install-path-for-composer) but it didn't work for me, I added installer-name key in extra, but no success.

Comment: May I ask what the reason is for your package to reside in `packages` instead of `vendor`?

Comment: yeah even i also believe in letting consumer decide the path, but i am doing a POC around a project where we just have too many modules and would like to define all of our custom work in separate space and not mixing with vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, and the documentation [says so explicitly](https://github.com/composer/installers#should-we-allow-dynamic-package-types-or-paths-no):

> [...] The ability for a package author to determine where a package will be installed either through setting the path directly in their composer.json or through a dynamic package type: "type": "framework-install-here".
>
> It has been proposed many times. Even implemented once early on and then removed. **Installers won't do this because it would allow a single package author to wipe out entire folders without the user's consent**. That user would then come here to yell at us.

(Emphasis mine)

The two keys you are using (`installer-paths` and `installer-name`) serve a different purpose than what you imagine:

- `installer-name`: allows the package author (you) to say your package should be installed under a different directory than `vendor/name`. In your case, instead of being installed on `vendor/demo/contentfeed`, it would be installed under `vendor/demo/packages` (because of your setting in `composer.json`)
- `installer-paths`: allows the package **consumer** to set a custom install path for a certain package or packages or package family. On a package `composer.json` has no effect, this setting is only for the project configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the config section into your `composer.json`, and define "vendor-dir" inside it

```
{
"name": "demo/contentfeed",
"description": "This is yet another Lumen composer package wrapper",
"type": "lumen-plugin",
"version": "1.1.5",
"keywords": ["demo","lumen","drupal"],
"homepage": "https://github.com/gauravmehrasrijan/lumen-feeds",
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "demo\\Contentfeed\\": "/src"
    }
},
"license": "MIT",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Gaurav Mehra",
        "email": "gauravmehra1987@gmail.com"
    }
],
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "packages/"
}
}
```

Reference:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir

Comment: That's a "project" setting, not a "package" setting.